# Extending records with additional fields

Tags: f#

I have a data pipeline where at each step more data fields are required. I would like to do this in a functional way by respecting immutability. I could achieve this with a class by I am wondering if there is an F# way of doing it?

```
// code that loads initial field information and returns record A

type recordA = {
    A: int
}

// code that loads additional field information and returns record AB

type recordAB = {
    A: int
    B: int
}

// code that loads additional field information and returns record ABC

type recordABC = {
    A: int
    B: int
    C: int
}
```

As records are sealed I can't just inherit them. How can I avoid having to define a new record with the exact same fields as the previous step and adding the required fields? Preferably I would like to have something like one record that has all required fields and the fields get assigned to their values in each step.

Note that the number of fields added in each step could be more than 1.

Answer (score 7):

I think this can be a good use case for the [anonymous records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records) recently introduced in F#.

```
let a = {| X = 3 |}
let b = {| a with Y = "1"; Z = 4.0|}
let c = {| b with W = 1 |}
printfn "%d, %s, %f, %d" c.X c.Y c.Z c.W
```

Comment: I would still have to define each record individually this way though and copy paste the fields from the previous record. I want to avoid having to change all records if I make a change to the base record. Is there a cleaner way to do the definition? Is something like this possible type recordAB = { record A with B: int }

Comment: @Gehaktmolen Actually you don't have to define the records individually or copy the data between them in this case.  This answer uses anonymous records, which don't have to be defined prior to using them, and it uses the 'copy-with-update' syntax `let b = {|a with Y = 2|}` to copy an instance of a record bound as `a` and additionally set the value of `Y`, creating a new instance bound to the identifier `b`.

Comment: Sadly the project is still on an older version of F# and this feature is not available to me :(. It would have achieved exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it in a very FP-style would be to use a DU with a case for each step of the workflow, and the appropriate data for each step in each case:

```ml
type WorfklowState =
| StepOne of int
| StepTwo of int * int
| StepThree of int * int * int
```

Then your entire workflow state, both what step you're currently on and the data produced/consumed by that step, would be modeled in the data type.  Of course, you would probably create record types for the data of each case, rather than using progressively larger tuples.

Comment: AFAIK anonymous records can be used in the union cases as a sort of tuples with named fields.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application, this may be a (mis-)use case for a dynamic data container.

F# might help by providing user-defined dynamic lookup operators, for which a special syntactic translation occurs.

```
let (?) (m : Map<_,_>) k = m.Item k
// val ( ? ) : m:Map<'a,'b> -> k:'a -> 'b when 'a : comparison
let (?<-) (m : Map<_,_>) k v = m.Add(k, v)
// val ( ?<- ) : m:Map<'a,'b> -> k:'a -> v:'b -> Map<'a,'b> when 'a : comparison

let m = Map.empty<_,_>
let ma = m?A <- "0"
let mabc = (ma?B <- "1")?C <- "2"
ma?A    // val it : string = "0"
mabc?C  // val it : string = "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "inherit" records:

```
type RecordA =
    {
        a : int
    }


type RecordAB =
    {
        a : RecordA
        b : int
    }


type RecordABC =
    {
        ab : RecordAB
        c : int
    }
```

Then you can access all of the elements, though with longer and longer chain as you go deeper and deeper.

However, why don't you just use a list of elements to store the result?

First, I would create a type to handle all possible types that you may have on each step, e.g.:

```
type Step =
    | Int of int
    | String of string
    // ...
```

Then you can represent the workflow simply as:

```
type WorkflowState = list<Step>
```

and if you want to ensure that you always have at least one element then you can use:

```
type WorkflowState = Step * list<Step>
```

However, the records have *labels* and the structure above does not have them! So, if you do *need* labels, then you can represent them by a map using either a strong type:

```
type Label =
    | A
    | B
    // ...

type WorkflowMappedState = Map<Label, Step>
```

or just a string based one, e.g.

```
type WorkflowMappedState = Map<string, Step>
```

The benefits of list or map based approach in comparison to the answers above is that you don't have to know the maximum number of possible steps. What if the number of steps is over 100? Would you want to create a record with 100+ labels? Most likely not! The anonymous records are great, but what if you want to use them outside of module where they were created? I *think* that that would cause some troubles.

Having said all that, I think that I would go with a list based approach: `type WorkflowState = list<Step>`. It is very F# way and it is very easy to transform further.